# Scala Array functions in Scala REPL

Tags: scala

I tried to create an array in scala.

In scala repl when i put dot and press tab i could see only few function available.

```
scala> val d = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
d: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
scala> d.
apply          asInstanceOf   clone          isInstanceOf   length         toString       update
```

But i was able to run sum, head ,tail etc on Array although scala repl didn't show them.

I couldn't understand why functions such as head, tail etc were not shown by scala repl.

Comment: If you press tab again a couple of times it should show them. As Dima explained those methods are not part of `Array` so they are not immediately shown, if you keep pressing tab the * REPL** searches for more methods. - I  any case, it should not affect you that they are not shown, you can still call them. Also, this may be another _(good)_ reason for preferring a`List` or any other real collection over an `Array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Array` doesn't actually have those methods. They are defined on either `ArrayOps` or `ArraySeq`. There are implicit conversions that allow you invoke those methods directly as if they were defined on array, but what really goes on when you do `array.sum` is something like `ArraySeq.make(array).sum`